# Play a Sound after a set delay once the UIButton has been pressed

Tags: objective-c, audio, uibutton, delay

I have an animation, the animation is set to play once "button one" is pressed.

I have made it so that a sound plays also when "button one" is pressed. However, I need the sound to be lip synced with the animation, so I need to be able to set a specific delay before the sound will play after the UIButton is pressed.

```
THIS IS MY SOUND CODE.
ViewController.h
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
@interface ViewController :UIViewController {
SystemSoundID SoundID;
}
- (IBAction)Button;
@end


ViewContrller.m
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);
}

- (IBAction)Button {
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
@end
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, which sets a timer to call a function after a certain duration of time.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(playNow) userInfo:NULL repeats:1];

-(void)playNow{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
```